# How to configure AWS Amplify for Javascript safely?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, frontend, aws-amplify

im using aws-amplify for user authentication, in the documentation it says that first it need to be configured like this:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    mandatoryId: true,
    region: something,
    userPoolId: something,
    userPoolWebClientId:something
  }
})
```

Im guessing these IDs shouldn't be seen by the client but I read somewhere that everything that is in the front-end can be seen by anyone who knows where to  look, so my question is: is there a way to really hide these keys and if not, then how can someone configure this library safely?